# What does CREATED container mean in docker?

Tags: docker

I am bit confused on the **status of the docker container**, especially with **status as CREATED**.

I know that when the **container is running** state it shows as below:

```
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:~/RAGHU/DOCKER# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1261afc2acc1        302fa07d8117        "/bin/bash"         43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes                           optimistic_thompson
```

And if the **container is stopped**, it shows as below:

```
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:~/RAGHU/DOCKER# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
935f902efac7        302fa07d8117        "/bin/bash"              44 minutes ago      Exited (0) 44 minutes ago                       competent_golick
5eb1c2525e2e        302fa07d8117        "/bin/bash"              44 minutes ago      Exited (0) 44 minutes ago                       friendly_saha
```

My confusion is  **in what state does the docker shows the status of the container as CREATED**:

```
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:~/RAGHU/DOCKER# docker ps -a | grep -i created
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
01c63f92586b        jenkins             "/bin/tini -- /usr..."   5 weeks ago         Created                                         gloomy_jones
```

Comment: Please refer to link: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Docker status `Created` means that the container has been created from the image, but it has never been started.

This state can be achieved in this two ways.

1. Docker container has been created using `docker create` command (this is done to speed up container creation).
2. Docker container has been created using `docker run` but it hasn't been able to start successfully.

For further information check `docker create` reference: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/

Comment: What are possible reasons behind container unable to start successfully?

Comment: @folex one of the reasons is that the ENTRYPOINT command is not valid

Comment: Does anyone know reasons behind container unable to start successfully, other than the one said by @ThachVan?

Comment: I see it's quite an old thread, I have the same issue on mac, and the entry point cannot be the reason, since it was working and suddenly it stopped working. On my end, restarting docker resolved the issue..

Answer (score -1):

You may be trying to run the container with a port that's already busy.