# How to remove all docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I use following commands to remove all docker containers:

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker stop
docker ps -aq --no-trunc -f status=exited | xargs docker rm
```

But anyway I see containers after:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
70cb7107d00d        24820714bfc6        "wait-for-it.sh mysqâ¦"   21 minutes ago      Created                                 sql_migration
```

Then, I executed the command:

```
docker rm sql_migration
```

And it removed the container.

Can you please help to correct initial command and explain why it doesn't work.

Also, I would be grateful if you explained how to change container to status like `sql_migration`

Comment: This might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723111/how-to-remove-old-and-unused-docker-images

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does CREATED container mean in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734412/what-does-created-container-mean-in-docker)

Answer (score 29):

## 1. Remove what can be removed...

To remove all `exited` and `created` containers but not the `Up` (running) ones:

```
docker container prune -f
```

`-f` or `--force` prevents you from being prompted to answer the following:

```
WARNING! This will remove all stopped containers.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N]
```

---

**example:** (Notice at the end that one container is not being removed)

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
053ce57276b7        alpine              "/bin/sh"           3 seconds ago       Created                                         eager_meninsky
55f20431a536        alpine              "/bin/sh"           15 seconds ago      Up 14 seconds                                   hardcore_clarke
44cbe2dc81b0        alpine              "/bin/sh"           38 seconds ago      Exited (0) 37 seconds ago                       test
647747afb9a4        alpine              "/bin/sh"           18 hours ago        Exited (137) 18 hours ago                       admiring_visvesvaraya


$ docker container prune -f
Deleted Containers:
053ce57276b7d7008272e95991cf950268b9b32676b1389ec6e8ab6e6b755dc9
44cbe2dc81b0522e0fd0e53f28a4d3871b818b9b17681dd011c8680ab37b51e7
647747afb9a431a2c5040e6aba5119b199b94061c444ff0194aaa809dbf849b8

Total reclaimed space: 0B


$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
55f20431a536        alpine              "/bin/sh"           45 seconds ago      Up 44 seconds                           hardcore_clarke
```

## 2. Stop all & remove...

```
docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)
docker container prune -f
```

---

**example:**

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
da7ffd8efb62        alpine              "/bin/sh"           5 seconds ago       Created                                         quirky_poitras
31cb71a8899c        alpine              "/bin/sh"           20 seconds ago      Exited (0) 13 seconds ago                       elastic_shaw
becfdc81228c        alpine              "/bin/sh"           25 seconds ago      Up 24 seconds                                   thirsty_murdock


$ docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq)
da7ffd8efb62
31cb71a8899c
becfdc81228c


$ docker container prune -f
Deleted Containers:
da7ffd8efb623677882b1534008e66a1530baa94e0473be537ef5c415c928ba3
31cb71a8899c47472d0ccb5710e34ff08b4ef142599d4e857e3e69740a2e59b5
becfdc81228cdf41519102ea780956eed71a86103e849dff3d9f7cca0a54651f

Total reclaimed space: 5B


$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Comment: Docker is not as straight forward as I think it could be when it comes to rebuilding containers.  For me, there was a learning curve, and since building environments is not something I do all the time, I forget the exact syntax of the commands.  I will have to remember these commands.

Answer (score 10):

I use the following command to remove all the docker containers:

`docker rm $(docker ps -aq)`

Answer (score 3):

I use the following commands to remove all containers:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

Answer (score 2):

Case 1. In order to remove only **Stopped Containers** use `sudo docker container prune -f`

```
$ docker container prune
WARNING! This will remove all stopped containers.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Containers:
4a7f7eebae0f63178aff7eb0aa39cd3f0627a203ab2df258c1a00b456cf20063
f98f9c2aa1eaf727e4ec9c0283bc7d4aa4762fbdba7f26191f26c97f64090360

Total reclaimed space: 212 B
```

Case 2. In order to remove all existing docker containers on system ( In all states -  **running / stopped / exited containers** )  use`sudo docker container ls -aq | xargs sudo docker container rm`,

**commands explanation**:

- `sudo container ls -aq` - lists all containers on system by continaer id filter.
- `xargs` - iteration over the pipe output and execution of command on each line
- `docker container rm <container-id>` - docker container removal

Answer (score 1):

One liner to stop / remove all of Docker containers:

`docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`

`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)`